# jQuery - widest item on page

Tags: jquery

How can I find the widest item (width set in css or as an attribute) on a web page using jQuery?

Comment: Whoa, widest thing with the width _explicitly_ set?

Comment: that width? body document window screen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wont be fast but should do the trick

```
var widest = null;
$("*").each(function() {
  if (widest == null)
    widest = $(this);
  else
  if ($(this).width() > widest.width())
    widest = $(this);
});
```

this should do the trick

this version might be slightly faster (but definitely not so clienat):

```
var widest = null;
// remember the width of the "widest" element - probably faster than calling .width()
var widestWidth = 0;
$("*").each(function() {
  if (widest == null)
  {
    widest = $(this);
    widestWidth = $(this).width();
  }
  else
  if ($(this).width() > widestWidth) {
    widest = $(this);
    widestWidth = $(this).width();
  }
});
```

I also suggest you limit the type of nodes you go through (ie. use div instead of *)

Comment: Might want to check outerWidth() if needed.

Comment: take care at the length of the DOM. this call can be costly.

Comment: Makes sense, I guess I was wishfully hoping for some kind of max function.

Answer (score 2):

Great answer Niko!

I've built upon it slightly so that it only shows the elements on the page which are visible, because sometimes it will return items that have a large width set but may have display:none set for example;

```
var widest = null;

$("*").each(function() {
    if (widest === null && $(this).is(':visible') ) {
        widest = $(this);
    } else if ( $(this).is(':visible') && $(this).width() > widest.width() ) {
        widest = $(this);
    }
});
```