# CSS, how to create a label width of the longest containing text?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with two columns, like this:

```
Firstname: Jeff
```

Where the first column is a label and the second one is an input. Now I'm setting the width of the label at 180px, but if there I have larger text (one word larger than 180px), it's not showed completely.

I've tried to set in css the width of the labels as 'auto', but I don't want different widths of labels in the same column.

The result shall look like this:

```
Firstname:    Jeff
Enciclopedia: Yes
Town:         Tokyo
```

How can I resolve this with Css?

Thanks a lot,

Jeff

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to wrap each label-input combination in a element, and then wrap that element in some container. This container should have a `min-width`, and `display: inline-block;`.
Then you let all the input items float to the right, and you're done.

This results in a very simple, clean and semantic markup with eqaully clean and maintainable CSS, and no requirements for JavaScript, jQuery, or other fancy stuff.

You could make something like:

```
 <form>
     <fieldset>
         <p><label for="lorem">lorem</label><input type="text" id="lorem" /></p>
         <p><label for="ipsum">ipsum</label><input type="text" id="ipsum" /></p>
         <p><label for="li">li</label><input type="text" id="li" /></p>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

with the css

```
 fieldset {
     min-width: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 fieldset input{
     float: right;
 }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/Rcdrc/) you can see how that looks.
Clearly you can style your form with margins, paddings etc.

And additionally if you want to have a wrapper that's semantically more accurate, [you can use a ordered list](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms). You can then style everything like you want to, and have even a nice additional wrapper (the `<ol>`) that you can use without adding semantic garbage.

A example would be:

```
 <form>
     <fieldset>
         <legend>First Example:</legend>
         <ol>
             <li><label for="lorem">lorem</label><input type="text" id="lorem" /></li>
             <li><label for="ipsum">ipsum</label><input type="password" id="ipsum" /></li>
             <li><label for="li">li</label><input type="text" id="li" /></li>
         </ol>
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset>
         <legend>Second Example:</legend>
         <ol>
             <li><label for="a">a</label><input type="text" id="a" /></li>
             <li><label for="b">b</label><input type="number" id="b" /></li>
             <li><label for="c">c</label><input type="range" id="c" /></li>
         </ol>
     </fieldset>

     <fieldset>
         <legend>Third Example:</legend>
         <ol>
             <li><label for="XXXXXXXX">XXXXXXXX</label><input type="email" id="XXXXXXXX" /></li>
             <li><label for="YYYYYYYYYYYY">YYYYYYYYYYYY</label><input type="search" id="YYYYYYYYYYYY" /></li>
             <li><label for="z">z</label><input type="text" id="z" /></li>
         </ol>
     </fieldset>
 </form>
```

styled by

```
  fieldset {
     border: 1px solid silver;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 10px;
     min-width: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 fieldset li{
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
 }

 fieldset label{
     margin-right: 10px;
     position: relative;
 }

 fieldset label:after{
     content: ": ";
     position: absolute;
     right: -0.2em;
 }

 fieldset input{
     float: right;
 }
```

would result in [this view](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ramsesoriginal/b6Taa/show/). You can even play around with it on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/b6Taa/

**EDIT to show how this adds no markup**

With the following html:

```
 <form>
     <label for="lorem">lorem<input type="text" id="lorem" /></label>
     <label for="ipsum">ipsum<input type="text" id="ipsum" /></label>
     <label for="li">li<input type="text" id="li" /></label>
 </form>
```

and the following CSS:

```
form{
    min-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

form input{
    float: right;
}

form label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}
```

You get [the effect that you want](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ramsesoriginal/Rcdrc/2/show/). You can play around with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/Rcdrc/2/). But adding `<fieldsets>` with `<legend>`s isn't adding unnecessary markup, on the contrary: it helps you to group the inputs. And [adding a `<ol>` is semantically correct too](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms), since the label/input combinations are semantic units and the form is a list of fields that have to be filled in a logical order.

Again, you can avoid the fieldsets, the lists, and everything and still achieve the desired effect, but semantically it would make sense to have at least the fieldset with a label..

**EDIT2: this is how a "real" registration form with good semantic markup may look like:**

```
 <form>
     <ol>
         <fieldset>
             <legend>Account</legend>
                 <li><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" required  /></li>
                 <li><label for="password">Password</label><input type="password" id="password" required  /></li>
         </fieldset>

         <fieldset>
             <legend>Personal Data</legend>
                 <li><label for="name">Name</label><input type="text" id="name" /></li>
                 <li><label for="surname">Surname</label><input type="text" id="surname" /></li>
                 <li><label for="dob">Date of birth</label><input type="date" min="1900-01-01" max="2012-02-17" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" id="dob" /><span class="additionalInfo">Please input the date of birth in the following format: YYYY-MM-DD</span></li>
         </fieldset>

         <fieldset>
             <legend>Contact Information</legend>
                 <li><label for="email">E-mail</label><input type="email" id="email" required placeholder="example@example.com" /></li>
                 <li><label for="tel">Telephone number</label><input type="tel" id="tel" placeholder="(555) 555-5555"
              pattern="^\(?\d{3}\)?[-\s]\d{3}[-\s]\d{4}.*?$" /><span class="additionalInfo">Please input the telephone number in the following format: (555) 555-5555</span></li>
                 <li><label for="url">Website</label><input type="url" id ="url" placeholder="http://www.example.com"></li>
         </fieldset>

         <li><input type="submit" /></li>
     </ol>
 </form>
```

and the styling:

```
 fieldset {
     border: 1px solid silver;
     margin: 10px;
     padding: 10px;
     min-width: 100px;
     display: inline-block;
 }

 fieldset li{
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     margin-bottom: 2px;
 }

 fieldset label{
     margin-right: 10px;
     position: relative;
 }

 fieldset label:after{
     content: ": ";
     position: absolute;
     right: -0.2em;
 }

 fieldset input{
     float: right;
 }

 fieldset li .additionalInfo{
     position: absolute;
     padding: 5px;
     margin-top: 5px;
     display: none;
     background-color: white;
     border: 1px solid black;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
     z-index: 10;
 }

 fieldset li:hover .additionalInfo{
     display: block;
 }
```

I included some additional info, to show you how it would all come together to one logical entity. Similarly you could include errors and whatever else you may want to include. This is just a quick example i threw together, but it's should show that you can achieve interesting things with this technique. One thing I also changed was that I put the `<ol>` directly under the form, so you don't have to repeat it for every fieldset. I personally find this somehow.. unpleasing, but since you want to have minimal markup, this would work pretty well and would be **very** accessible. Again, read [this article](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms) if you haven't. It provides some great insight in marking up correctly a form.

Oh, and the "real-life" example is visible here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/ramsesoriginal/b6Taa/9/show/

And you can play with it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/b6Taa/9/

**EDIT: i updated the last example**

There was an error in my code. The wrapper element (the `<li>`in the second and in the last example, the `<label>` in the minimal one and the `<p>` in the first one should have at least 1 pixel margin at the bottom, or else some browsers see the input fields as overlapping and won't float them correctly. I updated the last example so that it works there, everywhere else you should keep this in mind.

Comment: My problem with this is the massive amount of markup it adds. It's a personal thing, but I have no problem reducing the amount of markup by using 'progressively enhanced JavaScript'. Caveat: use profiling, as it can get slow depending on the number of fields.

Comment: it adds no markup? At most one wrapper tag, and you could even avoid that if wished (but semantically it would be nice to have, since a label and a input compose a semantic entity)..

Comment: It's all the `<ol>`s and `<li>`s. I find that they greatly reduce flexibility in the HTML. Where do you put errors, tips and other content? Depends on the exact nature of the project at hand, but in general, I find this to have similar problems to using tables.

Comment: I updated the question to show a version with minimal markup. And like I said in the question, (and you could read here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms ) adding a `<ol>` and `<li>` makes sense. Especially if you want to put errors, tips and other content in the form: the error for a given input should be grouped with the input somehow, as should be tips for the input or additional content. The fieldsets and lists are representing the logical structure of the form, not the graphical one.

Comment: I updated my answer to include a "real-life" example with some additional information and good markup (held to a minimum but still semantically correct)

Comment: What a great answer and follow through.  Came here to say that!

Comment: The jsfiddles you point to only work well in FireFox. IE works ok but is ugly, but in Chrome there's a lot of misalignment.

Comment: What version of Chrome and IE are you using? Do you have any special plugins active? Because I've tried it on every major browser, and I just checked again, and for me it works just fine..

Comment: I tried http://jsfiddle.net/ramsesoriginal/b6Taa/9/ in FF 41.0.1 and it works bad as inputs lands on different height than its labels. FullHD - so this is not a matter of screen resolution.

Comment: This is old answer but I just wanted to point that this fails real world forms with different sized input fields. In real life forms Zip field would not be the same length than address field for example.

Comment: We can put `<fieldset>` tags inside of `<ol>`/`<ul>` tags?  TIL, and I'm genuinely shocked.  I thought `<li>` was the ONLY acceptable tag inside an `<ol>` or `<ul>`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol says "Zero or more <li> elements" for "Permitted content".

Which is correct?

Comment: I want my inputs to take up the full size of the parent container. In your example it only works with a fixed width of the inputs - right?

Answer (score 10):

The easiest would be to select a fixed size large enough.

If you really want to simulate the exact behavior of a table you have two choices:

- use table
- simulate table with CSS:

  ```
  .block { display: table; }
  .row   { display: table-row; }
  label { display: table-cell; }
  ```

With the following HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <label>...</label><div class="value">...</div>
   </div>
   ...
</div>
```

I don't think there exists another way of dealing with this.
If you really don't want to change your HTML, your only hope might be to use javascript.

Comment: +1 to this answer. When someone wants all columns to be the same width (without js hacks)... *"Just use a table like its meant to be used"*. I don't understand this desire to shred up html and dogpile in css just to *TRY* and accomplish what `table` does naturally on every web browser since the dawn of time, and still going forward.

Answer (score 1):

simple solution would be to fix the length of the label which would accommodate the biggest lable (add some 50px extra so you can center it) and use `text-align:center`

Here's a fiddle for the same.. http://jsfiddle.net/mvivekc/4P58S/

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Set a minimum width which is the width of the typical widest label. Then use JavaScript to cope for edge cases. If the user doesn't have JavaScript, you can fallback to an 'OK' design.

Get the widest label in the form using the function from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1233380/582278), and then set the widths of all labels to that value.

This is a very similar setup to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3045546/582278) although that one is setting `<li>`s instead of `<label>`s.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modern method using CSS grid:

```css
.form {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content 1fr;
  grid-gap: .333em;
}

.label {
  grid-column: 1;
}

.input {
  grid-column: 2;
}

.wide {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <label class="label">Select</label>
  <div class="input">
    <select>
      <option>option</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <label class="label">Input</label>
  <div class="input">
    <input>
  </div>

  <label class="wide">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span>Checkbox</span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Hit and try to see what's the greatest label occupying. Assign that width to all other labels. Recommend you to put colons in a separate column. It looks clean.

Comment: I know what I have to do... the question is how

Answer (score -3):

try

```
label{
min-width:180px;
width:auto;
}
```

Comment: Now, all the labels that have the width less than 180px will have 180 px width, but the larger ones will have auto. So it's not the result I need; all the labels must have the same width.

Comment: if you allowed to use table then go with cram1010 <table>