# CSS inline form with aligned inputs to label length and input width is remaining space

Tags: html, css, forms

I want to create inline label and inputs, and I want all the labels to have the width of the longest label. This I have achieved and this is how my result currently look like:
[image]

The problem is that I want the input fields to be the width of the remaing space to the right, indicated in the image below:
[image]

This is the css for the form:

```
    form ol {
  margin: 0px;
  list-style-type: none;
  -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0px solid silver;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}

fieldset li{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

fieldset label{
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

fieldset label:after{
    content: ": ";
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.2em;
}

fieldset input{
    float: right;
}
```

And this is my html:

```
<form>
    <ol>
        <fieldset>
                <li><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" required  /></li>
                <li><label for="username">This is some long text</label><input type="text" id="username" required  /></li>
        </fieldset>

    </ol>
</form>
```

Once I set the fieldset width to 100% to fill the entire area, the input fields jump to the right as they have float right set.

What would be the best way to acheive keeping the inputs aligned to the longest label, but still use up all the remaining space? TIA!

Comment: `<fieldset>` inside `<ol>` is not valid html. See https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html

Comment: You are right, I took the code from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325426/css-how-to-create-a-label-width-of-the-longest-containing-text which was marked as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution using tables:

```css
form, table, input{
  width: 100%;
}

.label-col{
  width: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

label{
    margin-right: 10px;
}

label:after{
    content: ": ";
}
```

```html
<form>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><label for="username">Username</label></td>  
        <td><input type="text" id="username" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><label for="username2">This is some long text</label></td>  
        <td><input type="text" id="username2" required/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><label for="username3">This text is even longer heh</label></td>  
        <td><input type="text" id="username3" required/></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

If you know the max-width of your labels and/or are ok with clipping the label you can also use flexbox:

```css
form, fieldset{
  width:100%;
}

fieldset{
  border: 0 none;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

label{
  width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

input{
  flex: 1 1 0;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="username1">Username</label>  
    <input type="text" id="username1" required/>
  </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
    <label for="username1">This is some long text</label>  
    <input type="text" id="username1" required/>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label for="username2">This text is longer than the max width asd</label>  
    <input type="text" id="username2" required/>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Although I don't like using tables for layout purposes I accepted your answer as it does solve the problem and +1 for the width="1px" trick

Comment: I don't like it either. If you want to keep some of the semantics you can use css display instead of tables. e.g. `display:table;`

Answer (score 0):

Check this demo just you need to add float left to your form label:
Also I have mentioned the edits in css code. You can check it.

**Form Demo:**

```css
form ol {
      margin: 0px;
      list-style-type: none;
     -webkit-margin-before: 0em;
     -webkit-margin-after: 0em;
     -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
     -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
     -webkit-padding-start: 0px;
}
fieldset {
    border: 0px solid silver;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 500px; /** Added for fix **/
    display: inline-block;
}

fieldset li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden; /** Added for fix **/
}

fieldset label {
    position: relative;
    float: left; /** Added for fix **/
}

fieldset label:after{
    content: ": ";
    position: absolute;
    right: -0.2em;
}

fieldset input {
    float: right;
    width: 68%; /** Added for fix **/
}
```

```html
<form>
    <ol>
        <fieldset>
                <li><label for="username">Username</label><input type="text" id="username" required  /></li>
                <li><label for="username">This is some long text</label><input type="text" id="username" required  /></li>
        </fieldset>

    </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: your suggestion to float the labels left is an improvement, but you are still defining a width on the input of 68%, which means that it still can break if the label is very long or the area is small.

Comment: agree with @Ronnyvdb

Comment: @Ronnyvdb and Rohit Kumar, Actually the form has wrapping two sections the first sections for labels and second for inputs. we can't took width 100% for inputs sections. That's why that form inputs will come from left side of wrapper.

Comment: @SayedRafeeq yes your explanation of the problem is correct, but I am looking for a solution that would not wrap the two sections. Maybe this is impossible only using css

Comment: @Ronnyvdb, may be your requirement is quite different.. if you want to stretch the width of the inputs area you can do that with changing of wrapper width. :)