# CSS - Set Width of all label based on larger label width

Tags: html, css

I am rendering labels with it's value, but some of the labels are larger. i want all label should equal with depends on the large label width. I don't want to give static width for label. Below is the code and expectations. can this be possible in Flex or any other CSS?

```
<template for:each={record} for:item="rec">
        <div key={rec.fieldAPI}>
            <label> {rec.label} : </label>
            <p> {rec.value} </p>
        </div>
    </template>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can check this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325426/css-how-to-create-a-label-width-of-the-longest-containing-text

Comment: @ShafiqulIslam no the same question, i don't want to put static width, and i am not using form

Comment: you can get concept from this answer.

Comment: Give the div a class like so `<div class="div-class">`  then give that class the attribute display: `.div-class { display: inline-flex; flex-direction: column; }`  then give the label a class like so `<label class="label-class">`  then give that class the attribute flex:  `.label-class { flex: 1; }`  Note that "flex-direction: column" is used to put them on top of eachother.

Comment: You can use this code

    <style type="text/css">
      div{
    min-width: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
div label{
    display:block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
    </style>

    <div>
      <label for="lorem">lorem theee asdasd asdasd adsa adasd adsa sdas sadasd</label>
     <label for="ipsum">ipsum asdasd sd</label>
     <label for="li">li</label>
    </div>